# How to set a folder as namespace folder in visual C++ 2010？

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

How to set a folder as namespace folder in visual C++ 2010？And in this folder code ,automaticly,will be set in the namespace as the folder name.

Comment: IIRC, it does it for C#.

Comment: What the heck is a 'namespace folder'?

Comment: Why the close to vote as "Not a real Question`?  whilst `namespace folder` is misleading, for a programmer coming from C# this is a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't, and here's why:

In C#, those folders you create are physical folders, and new class files you create by right clicking that folder and going "Add Class..." will be placed in there, and the namespace for that class is of course, suffixed with the folder name.

However, in C++ these are not physical folders.  In fact, you'll notice that it doesn't say "New Folder...", but "New Filter...", e.g. a way of filtering out what kinds of files it contains.

It doesn't overly make sense in C++, (this is just my opinion).  In C# the class declarations and implementation are one and the same thing.  In C++ there are header files and implementation files (`.h` and `.cpp` respectively).  Now, I've seen folder-structure within header files, but it over-complicates things for implementation files.

This might not be immediately apparent to you in Visual Studio.  When you create a project, by default, all the `.h` and `.cpp` files are in the same folder.  This is not the case outside of Visual Studio, or even for projects I've worked on.  Some have `include` and `src`, with various subdirectories in `include`, and all of the source in a single folder.

TL;DR, it doesn't make as much sense to C++ as it does to C#.  That said, I use filters to create a logical "view" of my source files (by namespace), however this isn't indicative of how it is laid out physically.

Comment: Actually 2010 lets you have both: filters and regular folders. Well... Almost. The "Show All Files" icon in Solution Explorer switches to folder view, and you have "New Folder..." command. The drawback is: only files under vcproj's directory are shown in their folders, files from outside directories are shown at project level with a little arrow in their icons.